# How common is こちらこそ used? Is it considered very formal?

Tags: greetings, formality

If i meet a friend's friend and he/she says よろしくお願いします, would people usually say こちらこそ?

I saw this in the NHK japanese lesson page and was wondering if this is considered very formal and weird if i used it in a casual setting.

Comment: as far as online chatting is concerned, japanese people always answer it to me when I use 「よろしく」、「よろしくおねがいします」

Comment: I don't think こちらこそ is too formal. If your friend's friend is obviously younger than you, you can also use こっちこそ.

Comment: I don't think it's too formal or weird at all. In fact, it's probably important that you know how to use that phrase if you intend to interact with Japanese people, especially for academics or business. However, do keep in mind that depending on the setting and your relationship with the other person, you will need to know when you can simply say 「こちらこそ」 versus when you need to return the entire phrase back such as 「こちらこそよろしくお願い致します。」